# lazy high charts rails, what is "my_id" ? in <%= high_chart("my_id4", @chart) %>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I put lazy_high_charts in Gemfile, ran bundle, did rails g lazy_high_charts:install

so all necessary stuff done, this is how my controller looks like

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController

        def show
                @user = User.find(:last)


                @h = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
                        f.series(:name=>'John', :data=>[3, 20, 3, 5, 4, 10, 12 ,3, 5,6,7,7,80,9,9])
                        f.series(:name=>'Jane', :data=> [1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4,-46,7,8,8,9,9,0,0,9] )
                end

        end



end
```

this is how my view looks like

```
<%= high_chart("my_id4", @h) %>
```

this is how my layout looks like

```
    <title>Dashboard</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'highcharts' %>
  <!--[if IE]> <%= javascript_include_tag 'excanvas.compiled' %> <![endif]-->
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

I'm at a total loss, I don't see anything when I go to the url where the chart is supposed to appear

what is "my_id4" argument in highchart("my_id4", @h)

Comment: I used highcharts JavaScript without any gems. The highcharts takes a parameter which is the name of the container which will hold the chart. I guess "my_id4" is the name of the container. In your view add a div with an id "my_id4" and see the results.

Comment: thanks, helped me a lot, i figured it out just now

it seems the id tag wasnt needed, or it's only there to point to a specific div

the official documentation at github isn't correct, im on rails 3.1.4 and for that it said javascript include tag wasn't needed in the layout but it was, included that, and it worked

Comment: Then the my answer helped you? if yes tell me to move it to an answer to your question to help others who check your question get the answer and please accept it after that =).

Comment: lol yeh it did but not as a complete answer, it made me find the actual thing needed because after your comment I knew was doing the "my_id" part right

Answer (score 1):

use the "my_id" parameter to reduce multi highchart's div conflict in one page.

Answer (score 0):

For future users, you need to add `<%= yield %>` inside the `<body> </body>` of your page and only then can charts made in your Rails app controller become visible. [See more on yield.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

From the code above `<%= high_chart("my_id4", @h) %>` my_id4 is relevant and it is just like any other [CSS id](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_id.asp) in your CSS file. You can see the effect of this by simply adding this slight modification to your CSS file:

```
    #my_id4 {
        margin-left: 500px 
    }
```

You should see your chart noticeably move to the far right of your screen. 
Most times you just want your chart to apply on your page without any extra view modifications so you can leave out explicitly making a CSS id (in this case my_id4) and your chart will still show.